# How to handle multi user login in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have a website where one user loggs in and submit something then it moves to "user Two" which is having a seprarate username/password and then to "Third" and finally to "fourth". So I have to create a script in such a way that if first user is done submitting then the script should login with user two and then user three so that they can submit as well.

I 'm confused how to create the script so that multi user login can be made possible. Also i'll be using POM(Page object Model) to create scripts.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try [2D](https://www.javatpoint.com/data-structure-2d-array) array list for multiple users email id and password,Try this:

1.Using webdriver enter URL

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.test.com/");
```

2.Declare array.

> String arr[][]= {
>   {"user1@test.com","user2@test.com"} ,
>   {"Test@123","Test@123"} };

3.Then write code and logout current login user:-

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1 ; i++){

for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++) { 

//Find Login button     
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"username\"]")).sendKeys(arr[i][j]);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).sendKeys(arr[i+1][j]);

//Click on Submit button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"submit\"]")).click();

//Add your code
//Log out
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();           
        }    
    }
```

And another logic for this question is ,
we can run program using only one for loop

> String arr[][]= { {"user1@test.com","Test@123"} ,
>   {"user2@test.com","Test@123"} };

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{


driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();       

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"username\"]")).sendKeys(arr[i][0]);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).sendKeys(arr[i][1]);

//Click on Submit button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"submit\"]")).click();

//Add your code        
//Log out
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
Create 2D array list with all of the users ID and password, Then within two loops add your process commands 
1. login
2. submitting something
3. And finally command for logout this user.

Example:

```
String arr[][]= { {"user1@abc.com","user2@abc.com"} , {"password1","password2"} }

for(i=0; i<2 ; i++){
 for(j=0; j<1 ; j++){
// Your logic here for login, submitting and logout
}
}
```